# Approaches for overcoming 10000 file limit on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine currently has a 10,000 file limit per project.

I have a couple questions:

1. Has anyone seen any indications from Google that this will be increased? Why do they have such a small file limit?
2. My app has thousands of images. What are the options for reducing file count. Do I have to move the images to another hosting service... or can I zip them up somehow so that they don't all count towards the 10,000 file limit?

Comment: 10k limit is for code and related stuff that changes with new versions. there're no reason to store all images there, and upload all of them each time you update app version. as mentioned, you need Cloud Storage - https://cloud.google.com/storage/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have your app store the images in [Google Cloud Storage (GCS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), as app data, not as app static files, so they wouldn't count towards the app's 10k files limit.

Actually I shouldn't even call them app data, as they can be any files, not even related to GAE. And GCS can serve them like any other CDS, as illustrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15969224/4495081

You can find specific GCS integration notes for other Google Cloud Platform products including GAE [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/google-integration).

Comment: Can u provide a link to *GCS* ?