# Laravel 6 deployment on App Engine Standard too many files to deploy (Over 10,000)

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine

First query on here.

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel 6 app on Google App Engine Standard. I'm following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard

The app would not deploy due to there being over 10,000 files. I used gcloudignore to ignore the node modules and the app does deploy fine. However, this does make the app act differently as these dependencies are not available.

Is there a way to add the node modules after deployment? Or are there some modules I can ignore in particular that come with Laravel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is this 10000 files limitation. Checking the article, you should not face any issue of this limitation, which means that indeed, probably there are files on your Laravel that can be skipped.

I checked this other tutorial [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-web-app-on-google-app-engine-ecfbb0d49b00) and it seems to indicate files that you can skip, that you can give it a try - I would recommend you to look it, actually.

Besides that, you can verify the type of the files from Laravel and skip, for example, any possible images or text files that should not interfere, storing them separately, as mentioned on this other [Community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176127/approaches-for-overcoming-10000-file-limit-on-google-app-engine).

Let me know if the information helped you!