# pip install from a Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, pip, python-wheel

I would like to install a Python package (my-package-1.0.0.tar.gz) from a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

It works well with publicly available buckets ([Allow Public Read access on a GCS bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232188/allow-public-read-access-on-a-gcs-bucket)) or with signed url (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers). However I would like to know if there would be another solution.

I would like to have a private Python package, accessible from a user-friendly (or may I say developer-friendly-url) such as https://storage.googleapis.com/pypi-packages/my-package/my-package-1.0.0.tar.gz.

I would like this package to be accessible from other Google Cloud Platform tools such as Dataflow, Cloud ML, Composer or GKE

Do you think it's something doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a [custom domain](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) to your bucket in order to get the friendly url you desire and then make the object you desire accessible with the [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers).

To assign a custom domain you will need to create a bucket whose name is the same as the domain. For example, for a domain like ***www.anyname.com*** you will need to call your bucket `www.anyname.com`

After this you create a `CNAME` record that points to c.storage.googleapis.com.

Comment: Thank you but in this case, the repository will be public right?

Comment: Actually not, you can either set all objects as public or just a selected amount. Look at [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects]. You can use: `gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]` for a single object

Comment: I understand but if possible I would like to avoid to have to make my object public. Company requirements...

Comment: But, as I said in my answer, you can use the signed url to create a temporary link to be used. The object will still be private

Answer (score 3):

The way I found was to use a feature from GitLab : deploy token. Basically, this feature allows you to secure a url that can be used with pip install.

For instance :

```
pip install -e git+https://${GITLAB_PYPI_DEPLOY_TOKEN}@git.repo.net/my-repo.git#egg=my_repo
```

Please note that this is not really an answer to the initial question but a way that I solve my specific problem.